# HTML help - how to do a drop down container when you hover over on one of the menu choices?

Tags: drop-down-menu, containers

If you go to art.com , and put your mouse on one of the menu choices, such as "Rooms" or "Artists", You'll see a container with pictures and text. How I do that "container"?

Comment: Please read the [faq] and [about]. You need to of made some attempt to do this yourself and provide relevant code on what you tried, what failed, etc. etc. Your first port of call should be to learn CSS (cascading style sheets) and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has some great tools for that.

http://jquery.com/

You can check out library plugins for JQuery here:
http://plugins.jquery.com/